# Elasticsearch finding which indices contain hits when making use of an alias in query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I've 1000s of day-wise (time-based) indices in my cluster. Is there a way to monitor or find out at the ES Server side which indices `contain hits` when a query makes use of an `alias` . E.g. consider the below query that my customer fires:

```
GET index_alias/_search?q=Product_Serial_Num:ABCD
```

The alias `index_alias` is mapped to all the `day-wise indices` in the ES 6.8.6 cluster and they total `1200`. The reason being the query is used to fetch historical records for that `Product_Serial_Num`. Thus it is not possible to know beforehand which day-wise index would have data. That's the reason the `index_alias` is mapped to `all indices`. When the customer fires the above query, I would like to monitor this at the ES Server side and find out which `indices`  actually return the data when the query hits them. Is there a way to determine this without modifying anything at the customer end?

The purpose of this is to figure out the "which indices" are being hit the most, like  `last-n-days (30, 60, 90)`  and then apply hot-warm architecture accordingly like having last 60 days indices on hot nodes and rest on warm nodes.

Or if there are better ways to determine, please do share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should be already getting the information about the index in every hit metadata. Look at the sample response below:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_index_01",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "doc_id_1",
        "_score" : 1.0
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_index_01",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "doc_id_5",
        "_score" : 1.0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In the above response you can see that each hit contains meta fields and one such field is `_index`. The value of this field is actual name of index (not alias) where the document is found. You can use this information as per your needs.

The other way to find which index the alias is currently pointing to can be done by using GET alias api.

```
GET _alias/test_alias
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "test_index_01" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "test_alias" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

The above response provides the info about the `test_alias`.

Comment: Thanks Nishant. Let me edit my question to make my ask more clearer. Apologies. What I meant to say was - the client fires the queries and at the ES Server side, I wanted to be able to monitor it and deduce which are the indices that are being accessed the most.

Answer (score 1):

To complete @opster ES Ninja Answer.
You can have a part of information you need with [*_stats*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) api

In the *search* part, for each index, you will be able to know wish index is the most used

```
GET my_alias/_stats
"indices" : {
    "metricbeat-7.3.1-2019.12.05-000004" : {
      "uuid" : "2Jgl5tAfRBCUC8UjhzJMXw",
      "primaries" : {
        "docs" : {
          "count" : 4536039,
          "deleted" : 0
        },
        "store" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 1314781408,
          "reserved_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "indexing" : {
          "index_total" : 0,
          "index_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "index_current" : 0,
          "index_failed" : 0,
          "delete_total" : 0,
          "delete_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "delete_current" : 0,
          "noop_update_total" : 0,
          "is_throttled" : false,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
        },
        "get" : {
          "total" : 0,
          "time_in_millis" : 0,
          "exists_total" : 0,
          "exists_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "missing_total" : 0,
          "missing_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "current" : 0
        },
        "search" : {
          "open_contexts" : 0,
          "query_total" : 3,
          "query_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "query_current" : 0,
          "fetch_total" : 0,
          "fetch_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "fetch_current" : 0,
          "scroll_total" : 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "scroll_current" : 0,
          "suggest_total" : 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "suggest_current" : 0
        },
        ...
```